# Poor render performance in LibGDX with hexagonal map

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, polygon, 2d-games

So I am making a simple game using LibGDX which involes a 150*150 hexagonal map, and various types of cell, rocky, clear etc.

Problem is when i load the map, my computer almost completely freezes up and any movement thats supposed to be fluid (character moving, button highlights) take 5+ seconds longer than they should.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public void render(float deltY){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 100);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(); 

    polygonSpriteBatch.begin();
    for (int j = 0; j < 150; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
           offset = i%2 == 0 ? multipleX/2 : 0;
           if (mc.getMap().getRow(i).getTile(j).getTileType().equals(TileType.Rocky)) {
                drawCell(Color.BLACK, j, i);}
           if (mc.getMap().getRow(i).getTile(j).getTileType().equals(TileType.Clear)) {
                drawCell(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, j, i);}
        }
    }
    polygonSpriteBatch.end();
    stage.draw();
}

private void drawCell(Color color, int x, int y) {
    polySprite = new PolygonSprite(makePoints(color));
    polySprite.setX(mc.getMap().getRow(y).getTile(x).getTilePosition().get_x() * multipleX + offset);
    polySprite.setY(mc.getMap().getRow(y).getTile(x).getTilePosition().get_y() * multipleY);
    polySprite.draw(polygonSpriteBatch);
}


public PolygonRegion makePoints(Color color){
    side =  5;
    h = CalculateH(side);
    r = CalculateR(side);
    multipleX = (float)Math.sqrt(3)*side;
    multipleY = side+(side/2);
    float[] points = {      // vertices
            x, y,
            x+r, y+h,
            x+r, y+side+h,
            x,y+side+h+h,
            x-r, y+side+h,
            x-r, y+h};
    return new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(getTexture(color)),points
            , new short[] { //4 triangles using vertices to make hexagon
            0, 1, 5,
            1, 4, 2,
            5, 1, 4,
            2, 3, 4});
}
public Texture getTexture(Color color){


    Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    pix.setColor(color);
    pix.fill();
    textureSolid = new Texture(pix);

   return textureSolid;
}
```

I'm new to coding and LibGDX so there's probably something stupid i'm doing. Is there any way to render the map once and only redraw the polygons if they change?

Thanks

Comment: Remove every occurrence of the new keyword (don't create objects in frequently called methods), otherwise the GC will go crazy.

Comment: Use a tool or profiler to see where the time is being spent.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you are computing a square root for each cell, for each rendering pass.

So your code currently involves more than 22500 square root operations for each frame you render and is creating as many objects, that's quite a lot !

You should compute the points for your hexagons only once.

Comment: Good point, I moved all the calculations so that they are only called once when the program starts however it didnt seem to effect the performance. I beleive its something to do with the way I am generating the polygons (the render  method is called constantly so 22500 polygons are being generated many times per second). Maybe i am not deleting the old objects and it is filling up the memory? I'm really not sure though

Comment: Are you still instantiating PolygonSprites in your render method ? (Read Xoppa's comment)

Comment: Yes, I cant think of another way to do that though as i need different colored polygons depending on the contents of the map. Edit: tried instantiating one PologonSprite as black outside of the render method and calling polySprite.setColor(color) in the render but I just get a map full of black polygons. However, the performance problems have disappeared, I just need a way of setting the color.

Comment: Associate a polygon to each tile type : Instantiate a polygon for your "Rocky" tiles, and one for your "Clear" tiles. And choose from them according to the cell type when you have to draw. You'll just have to change the position of the polygon as you are already doing.

Comment: If you are just in need of color switching, you could also optimize by using a single polygon and changing the batch color before drawing. There are a lot of ideas to explore.

Comment: I have changed my draw method to:                                                private void drawCell(Color color, int x, int y) {
polygonSpriteBatch.setColor(color);
...      
polySprite.draw(polygonSpriteBatch);
    }                                                                                                                                 However all the polygons are still rendered as black (the initial value) even if i do setColor(Color.RED) they are all black. Is this what you mean by changing the batch color?

Comment: performance is fine now, i just need to find out how to do the color switching as polygonSpriteBatch.setColor() isnt working

Comment: Change the color of the polygon sprite object instead. It is highly probable that the PolygonSprite.draw method force the PolygonSpriteBatch color to the PolygonSprite color.

Comment: That also didnt work, i even tried changing both. However i have now created a different polygonSprite for each type of tile like you said and it is working well now, thank you for your help!!